# Changing the variable in a tibble using ifelse command or for loops

Tags: r

I am trying to change the element of a particular column in a tibble using ifelse command in a mutate function but it does not work. Below is the tibble and my code. I am trying to Change Bernice Sander's party to 'Independent' in the tibble below.

```
prez <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dereksonderegger/444/master/data-raw/Prez_Candidate_Birthdays')

prez <- prez %>%
  mutate(Party = ifelse(Party =='D','Democratic','Republican'))
prez <- prez %>%
  mutate_if(AgeOnElection ==79,Party <-'Independent')
```

Comment: `prez <- prez %>% mutate(Party = ifelse(AgeOnElection == 79, 'Independent', Party))`

Answer (score 0):

The last code can be

```
prez <- prez %>%
     mutate(Party = replace(Party, AgeOnElection == 79, "Independent"))
```

-checking the output

```
> prez %>%
   filter(AgeOnElection == 79)
# A tibble: 1 × 5
  Candidate      Gender Birthday   Party       AgeOnElection
  <chr>          <chr>  <date>     <chr>               <dbl>
1 Bernie Sanders M      1941-09-08 Independent            79
```

Comment: Thanks. But can an ifelse command work inside mutate function I keep getting errors when I try.

Comment: @khali-blinks Merci!  Bonjour!